# PathOverlay touch events are passed through every PathOverlay

Tags: android, dictionary, touch, overlay, osmdroid

I make online map and try to add touchable paths/tracks (I change their color when user touches them). On one map I have 6-7 PathOverlays with added onDown event handling:

```
private class PathOverlayExtended extends PathOverlay 
{
    public PathOverlayExtended(int color, Context ctx, long trackId, HistoryDetailFragment currentFragment) {
        super(color, ctx);
        trackIndex = trackId;
        fragment = currentFragment;
    }
    private long trackIndex;
    private HistoryDetailFragment fragment;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(final MotionEvent event, final MapView mapView) {
    fragment.onRoadClicked(trackIndex);
        return super.onDown(event,mapView);
    }

}
```

Then I touch one path on screen, it catches event and proceeds through every path. Important: it always starts from the same path (the one added to the Olerlays at the end).

When I replace "return super.onDown(event,mapView)" with "return true", only the last path catches the event and this is not the one I touch (but the one added to the Overlays at the end).

**How to check/distinct which Path I touched?**

Comment: You have to code that up...  it want happen by magic.  If you have lots of points in your path just compare the position to the screen position and test on the distance being close enough.  If you have long segments of path it's harder as you have to check the distance from each line segment to the point.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar for detecting a touch on filled Polygons. 
It's using Android Regions.

The principle is to "put" the Path that has been drawn in a "Region":
region.setPath(mPath, new Region((int) bounds.left, (int) bounds.top, (int) bounds.right, (int) bounds.bottom));

Then you check if the touched point is in this region with: 
region.contains(point.x, point.y);

No idea how this "contains" method is implemented, but it works, and seems quite efficient. Magic. I imagine it should also work for polylines.

You can look at the full code here: 
http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/source/browse/trunk/OSMBonusPack/src/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/overlays/Polygon.java

Comment: Seems quite interesting. I'm gonna take a closer look at it and try to use it in my code. Thanks!

Comment: I tried. Bad, bad, bad, it doesn't work properly. region.contains returns true if the point is "inside" the path, as if the path was closed.

Comment: So it was OK for a Polygon, but is KO for a Polyline. No more Magic, the solution from Ifor could be the only one.

Comment: Thanks for investigating this problem and sharing with us the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find fine solution to my problem, so in the end, I decided to do it in the following way.

Firstly, I made my own PathOverlayExtended class which iherits PathOverlay. Then I added some variables - bounds of the path region (maximum and minimum latitude and longitude).

Secondly, I checkced if tap coordinates fits in theese bounds. That way, I get only those paths which can be understanded as related to my tap.

In the end, I checked distances from tap coordinates to every line segment and chose the smallest one. That's it.

I used viesturz's answer, which helped me very much:

https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=36

Thanks for all answers!